# WatchKit, AttributedString formatting not working

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

I am building my first WatchKit App and am having troubles with `NSAttributedString` formatting as it does not seem to work as I'd expect ;)

This is my code:

```
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Menlo" size:30];
UIFont *hlFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Menlo-Bold" size:30];

NSMutableAttributedString *information = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@"ADDED AN ENTRY OF " attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textFont}];
NSString *amountString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",(-1)*handler.amount.floatValue];
NSNumber *underline = [NSNumber numberWithInt:NSUnderlineStyleSingle];
NSAttributedString *amount = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:amountString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : hlFont, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : underline }];

NSAttributedString *to = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:@" TO " attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : textFont}];

NSString *categoryString = handler.category;
NSAttributedString *category = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:categoryString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : hlFont, NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : underline }];

[information appendAttributedString:amount];
[information appendAttributedString:to];
[information appendAttributedString:category];

[_informationLabel setAttributedText:information];
```

and this the result:

[image]

**Expectation**

`10.00` and `Stuff` should be underlined and in boldface.

Is there something fundamentally different to how attributed strings work on the watch than on iOS? What am I missing?

read through this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, the problem were the fonts `@"Menlo"`.

By using

```
UIFont *textFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
UIFont *hlFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
```

the formatting with underlines works fine.

Comment: * will acceppt in 24 hours

Comment: Dont know why we can't use the fonts "Menlo" or another font in the apple watch?

Answer (score -1):

I don't believe you can programmatically set a label to be bold, italic, underlined....this has to be done through the actual interface in the storyboard.

According to [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceLabel_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKInterfaceLabel/setAttributedText:)

The attributes you can configure are

1. text
2. text color
3. font
4. min scale
5. alignment
6. lines

a potential workaround is to incorporate multiple labels, and set the ones you need to the right format (bold, underlined)

Comment: Nsattributedstring does exactly that: format individual parts of a string in a label.